# Send and Receive data from Game Center

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, game-center, multiplayer

I'm having a lot of trouble sending data between devices from game center multiplayer. I can establish a match and have both user connected but for some reason I can't send data. Here is my code:

```
-(void)sendData {
    NSError *error;
    int myScore = scoreInt;
    NSData *packet = [NSData dataWithBytes:&myScore length:sizeof(myScore)];
    [theMatch sendDataToAllPlayers: packet withDataMode: GKMatchSendDataUnreliable error: &error];
    if (error != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
    }    
}

-(void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID {

    NSLog(@"called");
```

}

I'm carrying my match from another view and I don't know if thats the problem but here is the code when game center finds the match:

```
 - (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)match
{
    MultiplayerView *mpv = [[MultiplayerView alloc] init];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    mpv.theMatch = match; // Use a retaining property to retain the match.

    match.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"Matched");
    if (!self.matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0)
    {
        self.matchStarted = YES;
        NSLog(@"Lets Go");
        MultiplayerView *mpv = [[MultiplayerView alloc] init];
        [mpv setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        [self presentModalViewController:mpv animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: David Bullard i have same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641113/issues-regarding-gamecenterios .But didnot get any answer.please help me.if u get any answers regarding this

Answer (score 1):

You must assign current view controller to your match delegate, otherwise match:didReceiveData:fromPlayer: will not work.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for that. (Would be awesome if the runtime complained about a nil delegate)